# CodeIgniter 4 plus Myth/Auth throws error when running Migrations via php spark migrate -all

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have discovered some wired behavior, I have that one CI4 project i am working on since a couple of weeks. everything is working just fine, but until now i have just been working with the project on my local machine. When i wanted to run the project on my Laptop in ran into an error when i tried to run the migrations with php spark migrate -all

```
CodeIgniter CLI Tool - Version 4.0.4 - Server-Time: 2020-07-20 06:16:02am



Running all new migrations...

An uncaught Exception was encountered



Type:        CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException

Message:     Unable to connect to the database.

Filename:    /opt/lampp/htdocs/sms/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Database/BaseConnection.php

Line Number: 425
```

The project includes Myth/auth, so i tried just to run "my" migration with php spark migrate . That just worked fine, no problem at all, the tables are there, no errors. Just for fun, i moved my Math/auth migrations from the vendor folder to the "normal" Database/Migrations folder and was able to migrate them that way.

That's very wired, especially since everything is working just fine on the PC I have been using before. There I am able to run the migrations using php spark migrate -all without any errors, when is set up a fresh MySQL/MariahDB database. But somehow only there.

I was able to reproduce the error on my laptop on my Manjaro partition, my Windows 10 partition and on my iMac.
So if you want to reproduce the error do the following:

1. `composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter whatever`
2. rename the `env` to .`env`
3. set `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development` and obviously uncomment that line
4. configure and uncomment your database setting in the .env
5. create a sample migration like the one from the docs using `> php spark migrate:create AddBlog`
6. add the following content  to the new migration and save the file:

   forge->addField([
                           'blog_id'          => [
                                   'type'           => 'INT',
                                   'constraint'     => 5,
                                   'unsigned'       => true,
                                   'auto_increment' => true,
                           ],
                           'blog_title'       => [
                                   'type'           => 'VARCHAR',
                                   'constraint'     => '100',
                           ],
                           'blog_description' => [
                                   'type'           => 'TEXT',
                                   'null'           => true,
                           ],
                   ]);
                   $this->forge->addKey('blog_id', true);
                   $this->forge->createTable('blog');
           }

           public function down()
           {
                   $this->forge->dropTable('blog');
           }
   }
7. run `> composer require myth/auth`
8. Edit app/Config/Email.php and verify that a fromName and fromEmail are set as that is used when sending emails for password reset, etc.
9. Edit app/Config/Validation.php and add the following value to the ruleSets array: \Myth\Auth\Authentication\Passwords\ValidationRules::class
10. Ensure your database is setup correctly, then run the Auth migrations: `php spark migrate -all`
11. As a result you will also have the above error. I was not able to
    get around that error, except for the system in was working with at
    first.
12. If you just use `php spark migrate` it will migrate the sample migration without any errors

Comment: Yes I came across this too... But if you drop all of your tables and run "php spark migrate" it will not create the tables. You need to run "php spark migrate -all". Even though you get the errors, it will create the tables.

Comment: I have moved the migrations file to the database/migrations folder and ran "php spark migrate -all" after dropping all of the existing tables, and as you observed, that works without generating errors... Now to find out why.

Comment: So this all suggests that its an issue in CI 4 when using the -all option. It's totally unrelated to mythAuth.

Answer (score 2):

I am running CI 4.04 on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, running apache2.4.29 and PHP 7.4.9

**The short answer is...**

Using `php spark migrate -all` searches everywhere it knows about for Database/Migrations Folders and files.

There just so happens to be a such folder/file under

```
tests/_support/Database/Migrations/2020-02-22-222222_example_migration.php
```

**The bits added to make the short answer longer**

So the Database error we are seeing is due to not having set up Database credentials for $tests in **/app/Config/Database.php**

All it's doing is looking to connect to the DB set up under $tests, but appears not to actually run as we don't want it to.
That appears to be enabled when ENVIRONMENT is set to "testing".

**So 3 options for the time being...**

1. Ignore the error. *But that always leaves you wondering what's really happening.*
2. Setup the credentials for the $tests Database. *(Not really warranted.)* OR
3. Delete/Rename the tests folder if you are not using it. *(Stop it finding it.)*
4. Would be to use the -n switch/option and specify the namespace to use (but not sure that's working.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis. Thats defenetly the errors source. For now, I decided to go with option three.

Comment: @Tristano Well it was fun to figure out what was going on. That's how you learn.

Answer (score 0):

Changing DB hostname to '127.0.0.1' from localhost in your .env file usually solves the problem of running any migrations from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Open your PHP.ini file, find this :

> ;extension=sqlite3

and remove the semicolon to activate sqlite3. You need this library in Codeigniter 4 in order to use FORGE.